# Rational Software Architect - missing icon for Class element in palette window?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have been trying to create a Class diagram in UML 2.0 using Rational Architect.

However when I look at the palette options there is no icon for Class to click and position a class item on the diagram.

Screenshot:

[image]

Following this example [here](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~harmon/cis540f09/CIS540-lab2.pdf) , on page 2 you can clearly see the palette has an icon for "Class"

Why can I not find it? Is it a specific type of project or model I have to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved,

Was in "Use-case" view instead of "Model" view.

[image]